# remove elements from list of strings while traversing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

how to remove elements from a list of strings while traversing through it.
I have a list

```
list1 = ['', '$', '32,324', '$', '32', '$', '(35', ')', '$', '32,321']
```

i want to remove `$` fro the list and if a `)` or `)%` or `%` comes add that to the previous elemt of the list.
expected output is :

```
['', '32,324', '32', '(35)', '32,321']
```

what i have tried is

```
for j,element in enumerate(list1):
   if element == '%' or element == ")%" or element ==')':
      list1[j-1] = list1[j-1] + element
      list1.pop(j)
   elif element == '$':
      list1.pop(j)
```

but the output i am getting is

```
['', '32,324', '32', '(35)', '$', '32,321']
```

whis is not the expected output. Please help

This question is different from the suggested reference is, here I have to do a concatenation with the previous element if the current element is `)`,`)%` or `%`.

Comment: It will probably be easier for you to copy the elements you want to a new list instead of trying to filter it AND traverse it at the same time.

Comment: What about  the output of `["(3", "$", ")"]`?

Comment: @LanteDellarovere, that also should be concatenated to the first element and the last two should be removed, output: `["(3$)"]

Comment: Why is `"$"` included in the output?

Comment: if `["(3$")]` is the output I think you should re-formulate the rules, because there are incongruences

Comment: Question have been put on hold few seconds before I've posted my answer. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Aah7HG1m) is code which works without clonning list, check it.

Comment: @OlvinRoght If you believe you have a solution which is not already covered by any answer on the duplicates, you should post it there. Duplicate are meant to gather all answer at the same place, not to prevent new good answers.

Comment: the question isn't different. The problem is that you cannot use `pop` when iterating on a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Green Cloak Guy said is mostly correct. Editing the size of the list (by calling `.pop()`) is causing you to have an unexpected `j` value. To me, the easiest way to fix this problem while keeping your existing code is to simply not mutate your list, and build up a new one instead:

```py
new_list = []
for j,element in enumerate(list1):
   if element == '%' or element == ")%" or element ==')':
      ret[len(ret) - 1] += element  # add at the end of the previous element
   elif element != '$':
      new_list.push(element)
```

However, I would encourage you to think about your edge cases here. What happens when a ')' is followed by another ')' in your list? This may be a special case in your if statement. Hope this helped!

Comment: Nice call about edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of attempting to remove and merge elements dynamically while iterating on the list, it will be much easier to make a new list based on the conditions here.

```
list1 = ['', '$', '32,324', '$', '32', '$', '(35', ')', '$', '32,321']

out = []
for element in list1:
    if element == "$":
        continue #skip if $ present
    elif element in ("%", ")", ")%"):
        out[-1] = out[-1] + element #merge with last element of out so far.
    else:
        out.append(element)

print(out)
#Output:
['', '32,324', '32', '(35)', '32,321']
```

Comment: `if element in ("%", ")", ")%"): ... elif element != "$": ...` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this list comprehension works (haven't seen an example of how `%` is handled):

```
[ (a+b if b in (')',')%','%') else a) for a,b in zip(list1,list1[1:]+['']) if a not in ('$',')',')%','%')]
```

The idea is to:

- make a list of pairings of elements and their successors
- filter out elements that should be removed
- add the successor as appropriate to those that we keep